# Vue.js passing an array of props to a dynamic component

Tags: vue.js

I can display the last element in the array of data I'm passing via props to my child component, but I need to display ALL the data from the array. You can see what's going on with the app at this link: [View Vue.js app here](https://bc-only-rates-trimakas.c9users.io/)

I have a dynamic parent component:

```
<credential_details
  xs12
  class="no_background"
  id="credentials"
  v-for="(item, index) in components"
  :index="index"
  :key="'fourth' + index "
  :seller_id="seller_id"
  :selected_marketplace="selected_marketplace"
  :token="token"
  >
</credential_details>
```

Here is my `data` function in the parent:

```
 export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      seller_id: "",
      selected_marketplace: null,
      token: "",
      components: [],
    };
  },
```

I am retrieving data via axios in the parent component, like this:

```
let self = this;    
axios.get(url + '/return_credentials').then(response => {
  response.data.forEach(function(element){
    self.seller_id = element.seller_id;
    self.selected_marketplace = element.marketplace;      
    self.token = element.auth_token;
    self.components.push(1);
  });
  if(self.seller_id == ""){
    self.show_cancel_button = false;
  }
  self.show_cancel_button;
});
```

And then displaying it in the child component like this:

```
props: ["seller_id", "selected_marketplace", "token"],
```

And then inside the code like this:

```
<v-text-field
  required
  :error-messages="sellerIdErrors"
  color="indigo"
  label="Amazon Seller Id"
  v-model="seller_id"
  prepend-icon="person"
  @input="$v.seller_id.$touch()"
  @blur="$v.seller_id.$touch()"
></v-text-field>
```

This is great, but it only displays the last element in the array, how do I display ALL of the data?

Comment: What array do you mean?

Comment: @RoyJ the array that's returned from axios..  this one `response.data`

Comment: where I'm doing this `response.data.forEach(function(element)`

Comment: You would need to have the array in your `data`, assign to it, and probably use `v-for` to display multiple `credential_details` components.

Comment: your v-for="(item, index) in components"  :index="index"
  :key="'fourth' + index "  but your props read props: ["seller_id", "selected_marketplace", "token"],  seems like v-for not affect all elements